# SMS/text message notifications on answers to your question

Tags: feature-request, notifications, mobile-web

Sometimes answers to your question can happen many minutes, hours, or even days after you asked the question. In the case of days, the e-mail notifications are certainly enough (and just noticing the site), but many of my questions end up not having answers for a good 20-30 minutes.

**I'd like to be notified of new answers by SMS (text message), the moment the answer is posted.** I always have my cellphone with me, and I already use it for PUSH type notifications from other things (including emails, with auto-forwarding to my cell number @vtext.com). I would just use the auto-forwarding trick with SO too, except that it doesn't offer the option to send an email with each answer, the moment the answer is posted.

Comment: You kinda just did suggest that.

Comment: For those keeping score at home, I believe we've now had requests for notification via: SMS, email, Twitter, Facebook, a friends system a la LinkedIn, smoke signal, sky-writing, carrier pigeon, and note tied around a brick and thrown through your window.

Comment: I removed the bottom sentence. Didn't realize meta stack overflow was actually the place to suggest stuff, until it required the feature-request tag. @Pesto I couldn't find anything about SMS or related terms when I searched, but perhaps I missed, would you like to cite a link to a duplicate request?

Comment: @Pesto: So that's where that brick came from...didn't realize I was part of the beta test. A little heads-up next time would be nice.

Comment: @Eric: Heads up?  It would probably be more prudent to duck.

Comment: ++ @Pesto, very funny

Comment: rofl            :)

Comment: Any notification should also include notifications about new comments, so the question asker can quickly respond to those. (And sending that many SMS messages, worldwide, will be costly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to interrupt the brick throwing puns but here's a serious answer to the question...

[http://notify.me/](http://notify.me)

Sign up there, add your phone as a SMS destination, and then at the bottom right corner of any question is the RSS logo and "question feed"; copy that and paste it into notify.me as a source. Then go to the account tab, sources list and enable SMS for each question feed.

SMS doesn't seem like a hard thing to implement. It's an email address. But perhaps it would be too many emails to send out, I don't know. How do other really popular sites manage it? I suppose it's a cost that wouldn't be justified, it wouldn't make SO any extra money so why implement it. Oh well, hopefully notify.me will do its job...

Comment: But I can't find a feed to subscribe to answers

Comment: So we have to subscribe to individual question feeds?

Comment: Notify.me is broken.

Comment: The service is gone and the domain name is for sale.

Answer (score 6):

Since this question was posted back in 2009, some things have changed.

Nowadays you can install the official Stack Exchange app, which will give you a notification when one of your questions is answered. This is on by default, but can be turned off if you want. Also, it lets you choose if you also want to be notified during "quiet hours" or not.

It's not exactly the same as SMS, but (barring carrier issues) it has the same effect and can be customized as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good suggestion, but I do not believe the SO team would implement that feature any time soon. This site is kept pretty simple and to the point. Maybe in the future, but I do not see that as a priority.

Personaly, I would probaly not use sms notifications due to costs/annoyance, but I know some people could find that useful.