# Send SMS when someone answers question

Tags: feature-request, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMS/text message notifications on answers to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/sms-text-message-notifications-on-answers-to-your-question)

Is it possible to send SMS to people when their question is answered? Currently they have to keep refreshing SO page to see if their question is answered.

Comment: Any notification should also include notifications about new comments, so the question asker can quickly respond to those. (And sending that many SMS messages, worldwide, will be costly.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in mechanism for this. However, you should receive notifications through the site automatically when you get a new answer, so there's no need to refresh manually. There are also [an assortment of apps](http://stackapps.com) for all the major computer and mobile platforms that can alert you when you have new answers.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way but if you insist, you can change the [settings to get an email](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) be sent to you whenever your question gets answered.

Perhaps, instead of an email, add an [email to SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) address and be sent a SMS to your phone.

---

Crazy idea:

- [Convert your inbox to RSS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85897/is-there-a-rss-to-the-stack-exchange-inbox-how-about-to-activity/135045#135045)
- [Convert RSS to email](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/)
- [Convert email to SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways)

Comment: Emails are not sent directly though (every 3 hours, or even less). I'd rather have a question asker stick around to respond to comments, at least in the first hour after asking a question.