# How can I get Stack Overflow notification on my mobile?

Tags: support, notifications, mobile-web

I would like to get Stack Overflow notifications on my mobile as an SMS alert.

Is it possible to get notifications via SMS?

Comment: Check the answer of this question: [SMS/text message notifications on answers to your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/sms-text-message-notifications-on-answers-to-your-question)

Comment: There is an android app in alpha testing that does notifications.

Comment: @Joe: Those aren't SMS, though.